# easy way to replace components in visual studio C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, components

I made a GUI using C# for my project using default buttons, graphs and other components available in visual studio. Now I have installed DotNetBar for cool components like tabs buttons etc and want to replace them with the old ones. Is there an easy way to do that so that just replacing (for example a button) associates the code with the newly added button...?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Replacing "cool components" with old ones is pretty unusual.  A component vendor might have a way to automatically upgrade old controls but they are not likely to make it easy to remove them again.  You make it easy by just doing them one at a time, not much more can be said about it.

Answer (score 1):

No, as much as I know there is no easy way unless the producer of the new controls provides an automated tool for the job.

The main reason lies in the difference in property names, methods name and above all the event handler signature between the standard controls and the new ones. You could be lucky if the third party controls have the same properties, methods and events of the standard one, but usually they have implemented new functionality and extendend the base one and this usually causes broad incompatibility.

Then there is the need to manually edit every project file to substitute the references from the standard controls to the new ones and this is also a complex work that only the producer of the control could resolve

Comment: Agree with Steve, there are a very small number of scenarios where you could do a search and replace in the cs and designer.cs files, namespace and class name. All depends on how different the classes are. Have to look at it on a case by cases basis.